# UIAlertView clickedButtonAtIndex is not called

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, uialertview

this is how I create the alert:

```
UIAlertView* dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];

dialog.delegate = self;

//some options

aField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0,45.0,245.0,25.0)];
[aField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[dialog addSubview:appkeyField];

[dialog show];
[aField release];
```

However

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView 
                  clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSLog(@"test here");
}
```

does nothing. There is nothing in the log! What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you place the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol in the header?

Comment: thanks that was the prob, make this an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the `delegate` property of an object, your class must adopt the appropriate protocol. In your case, you are using a `UIAlertView`, so you need to add the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol to your header file:

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

To add multiple protocols, use:

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController <Protocol1, Protocol2, ...>
```